# Escaping Terraform String Properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm

How can I properly escape a Terraform string for trying to be interpolated that contains double curly braces? I'm reading a json file using templating and it keeps failing on this issue.

```
"customInventory": "{{ customInventory }}"
```

I want to keep the double braces. Nothing works so far and this is preventing the correct passing of this value to an Amazon Web Services Ssm doc. The Terraform documentation doesn't provide much insight other than escaping quotes and dollar signs.

I've tried Unicode values, double braces, backslashes and other permutations without any success.

Comment: give the full codes first and provide the error logs.

Comment: Full logs shouldn't be required to answer string escaping itself? I'm saying it's a string with double brackets and want to ensure it stays as double brackets. The error isn't helpful as it's a mistake by the string processing as it assumes you are providing a variable. I'll try to add the error details tomorrow to increase the detail in case this is still required.

Comment: I would create an inline template for it instead, interpolation will be hard in this case.

Comment: Full code and the error messages would be helpful here because `{{` and `}}` isn't actually Terraform template syntax, so it seems like something else is going wrong here.

Comment: @martin you were right on. I updated with answer as I finally figured out what it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is AWS Ssm doc parameter syntax. The error was actually not terraform but AWS reporting back invalid input when attempting to create the doc. Changing to `Enabled` instead of `{{ customInventory }}` resolved the issue and allowed me to publish the doc.